# Monitor mirroring

Tags: centos, vnc, remote-desktop

I need to mirror a remote monitor from a server running `CentOS 6.5`.

With `VNC` I'm able to connect to the :0 display (that it's the one it is shown on the remote server monitor) but when I change user on the server without logging out it obviously opens a new display and the local screen became useless. Are there any options to overcame this issue ?

Starting `VNC` before logging could achieve this ? Unfortunately I run into a bug (I've asked on a `CentOS` forum) and I can't start `VNC` that way because I'll need to upgrade some packages that could cause some stability issues.

If this works good to know (I can use `VNC` on other servers) but other options are really appreciated.

Comment: Now I fixed the VNC login issue but the monitor mirroring problem remain unresolved